# create user with umbraco webservice

Tags: api, umbraco

I'm trying the following code:

```
var myCarrier = new memberCarrier()
        {
            DisplayedName = "abemad123",
            Email = "abemad123@gmail.com",
            LoginName = "abemad123",
            MembertypeId = 1062,
            Id = 3,
            Password = "abe"
        };

        var client = new UmbracoWebService.memberServiceSoapClient();
        var tmp = client.create(myCarrier, 1062, "abemad123", "abemad123");
```

But I get this error:

> Server was unable to process request. ---> No User exists with ID -1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I get an exception with the message "Server was unable to process request. ---> No User exists with ID -1"

Answer (score 1):

Bug in Umbraco.

If user/pass to the webservice doesn't match it throws an exception "No User exists with ID -1"

Error should be: "Wrong password"

Comment: please provide the link from where you got this info and accept your answer. This will be helpful for others having same issue.

Comment: Uhm, I just changed the password I provided and suddenly it worked. Well, it cannot set the email, which is annoying